# How to put a cropped image on a Tkinter Canvas in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, crop

I found a lot of similar questions, but not quite the solution to this case : 
I want to

1. Load an image file from disk
2. Crop it (lazy or not)
3. Place it on a TKinter canvas

And oh, it would even be better that step 1 would not need to be a gif-file, but even if it has to be I'll be happy. That's it..

I can load a file, I can crop it (In PIL) I can place it on a canvas (In TKinter), but I don't seem able to combine it all.. (So maybe a simple cast from PIL to TKinter is enough?)    I'm a newbee in TKinter of course.

Comment: In the future before posting this on stackexchange you might want to try implementing at least one step of your algorithm before expecting others to write it for you.  Looks like you got lucky with this one. EDIT: No idea why this post showed up for me just now, 3 years after it was made.

Comment: @Darren , indeed 3 years ago... And of course I had tried to implement it, there was just no use posting the code other then proof I had worked on it.  I cannot see the value of posting code for loading a file, cropping it and place it on a Canvas when I.m not stuck on it.  Besides I love to code , I would hate it when others wrote my code for me :)  I was stuck on missing out a library not on a certain piece of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [`ImageTk`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm) module in `PIL`.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

im = Image.open("image.png")
cropped = im.crop((0, 0, 200, 200))
tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(cropped)
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=tk_im)

root.mainloop()
```