# How can I display an image in Python 3 using tkinter/ttk?

Tags: image, button, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

The nub of the matter is, what am I doing wrong in the following code snippet?

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *

    root = Tk()

    myButton = Button(root)
    myImage = PhotoImage(myButton, file='myPicture.gif')
    myButton.image = myImage
    myButton.configure(image=myImage)

    root.mainloop()
```

The error message I get from idle3 is as follows:

```
    >>> 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/bob/Documents/Python/tkImageTest.py", line 9, in <module>
        myButton.configure(image=myImage)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1196, in configure
        return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1187, in _configure
        self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
    TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Button)
    >>>
```

This error message has me stumped, I simply don't understand what it is trying to say. Any ideas?

I would also appreciate suggestions for changes...

Comment: BTW I have already checked this reference http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm - you will see my code snippet looks very similar!

Comment: The error seems to point to the `myButton` argument passed to `PhotoImage()`. I don't believe that `PhotoImage()` takes a reference to a widget object, so this may be causing the error. Try that line without it, such as `myImage = PhotoImage(file='myPicture.gif')`

Comment: @Gary, that seems to do it. I was misled by some of the documentation (and some other errors I had generated) to thinking the `PhotoImage` needs an explicit reference to the root window. After some more fiddling I found the reference to either the root or the button itself can be provided by another configuration option on the `PhotoImage` constructor like this, `PhotoImage(master=myButton, file='myFile.gif')`, but the way I have written it, it looks to Tkinter like a name, which is supposed to be a string, ofc.

Comment: Got it. Turned my comment into an answer and added some other useful info.

Comment: See the code given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142509/how-to-put-a-cropped-image-on-a-tkinter-canvas-in-python/9142771#9142771

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error seems to point to the `myButton` argument passed to `PhotoImage`. As you noted in your comment, `PhotoImage` was treating the widget object as a string (there are several options of type string; see a list of PhotoImage options [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/x6716-options.htm)).

Your code will work if you implement that line without referencing the `myButton` object:

```
myImage = PhotoImage(file='myPicture.gif')
```

I'm not certain you need to alter the `PhotoImage` constructor. Look at the `PhotoImage` docs to determine the valid options (i.e. resource names) for that class. Quoting the help file:

> Help on class PhotoImage in module tkinter:
>
> class PhotoImage(Image)
>
> ```
> | Widget which can display colored images in GIF, PPM/PGM format.
> |    
> |  Method resolution order:  
> |      PhotoImage  
> |      Image  
> |      builtins.object  
> |    
> |  Methods defined here:
> |    
> |  __getitem__(self, key)  
> |      # XXX config  
> |    
> |  __init__(self, name=None, cnf={}, master=None, **kw)  
> |      Create an image with NAME.
> |
> |      Valid resource names: data, format, file, gamma, height, palette, 
> |      width.
> ```

---

FYI: The easiest way to get to the docs from Python at the command line or from IDLE:

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage
help(PhotoImage)
```

And lastly, another useful link about this class is at http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/PhotoImage.

Comment: Many thanks Gary! You are right about the 'master' reference, too. That was a hang-over from some experiments I was doing with multiple threads (best not to ask!).

Comment: @Bobble BTW, if this answered the question, please mark it as the accepted answer (this looks something you can do for a few of your questions).

Answer (score -1):

I tested the example with python 2.7.9, 3.2.5, 3.3.5, 3.4.3 in 32bit and 64bit.
(Win 8.1 64bit)

The code works.

( in python 3.4.3 64bit I had first an error message.

I've completely uninstalled 3.4.3 and then reinstalled.

Now, the example works also with 3.4.3 64 bit )

```
# basic code from >>
# http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/PhotoImage

# extra code -------------------------------------------------------------------------
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

import sys
import platform

print ()
print ('python    ', sys.version)
print ('tkinter   ', tk.TkVersion)
print ()
print (platform.platform(),' ',platform.machine())
print ()


# basic code -------------------------------------------------------------------------

root = tk.Tk()

def create_button_with_scoped_image():
    # "w6.gif" >>
    # http://www.inf-schule.de/content/software/gui/entwicklung_tkinter/bilder/w6.gif
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file="w6.gif")  # reference PhotoImage in local variable
    button = tk.Button(root, image=img)
    # button.img = img  # store a reference to the image as an attribute of the widget
    button.image = img  # store a reference to the image as an attribute of the widget
    button.grid()

create_button_with_scoped_image()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you sure that's an answer, and more specifically an answer for python-3.x?

Comment: A good answer is not only a working answer but also a documented one. There's no point supplying code if the OP doesn't understand it. He/she should learn something from the answer instead of just copy pasting it, that way he/she'd end up asking the same question again next time, only in a different context.

Comment: the point is that the response from gary and the Tkinter Wiki for me does not work in Python 3.4.3

Comment: I have edit my post; ( in python 3.4.3 64bit I had first an error message.

I've completely uninstalled 3.4.3 and then reinstalled.

Now, the example works also with 3.4.3 64 bit )