# Opening images using tkinter on python 3

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, tkinter

I made the following (and very short) code on Python 3:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("Trollface.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = photo)
```

When I run it, I just get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Comp Sci/USB_Virus/trollface_puzzle_picture.py", line 12, in <module>
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3416, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3357, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
RuntimeError: Too early to create image
```

What am I doing terribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `Tk` first:

```
root = Tk()
```

---

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(width=500, height=500, bg='white')
canvas.pack()
image = Image.open("Trollface.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=photo)

root.mainloop()
```

The code above essentially comes [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9142771/190597).