# Getting PNGs to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am not sure how to get PNGs show up Python. When I tried the following code, all it gave was an error, even when I got the PNG image on the same folder as the Python program is.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

an_image=PhotoImage(file="test.png")

root.mainloop()
```

And I got the error shown up as exactly the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/school stuff/2018/IT Advanced/python projects/random testing/buttonimage.py", line 7, in <module>
an_image=PhotoImage(file="test.png")
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "test.png"
```

Is there some way to make the PNG show up on the program GUI?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: The error is way too long to be useful, but I tell some parts of what is in the error message.

Comment: Ok, edit your question to include that error.

Comment: Put the [PhotoImage in a Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9142771/190597) or a [in a Label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28140228/190597).

Comment: With "PIL", it seems it doesn't work on my Python 3.6.3. What do I change to make it compatible?